# how to detect the coordinates of certain points on image

Tags: c++, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]

I'm using the ORB algorithm to detect and get the coordinates of the crossings of rope shown in the image, which is represented by the red dot. I want to detect the coordinates of the four points surrounding the crossing represented by the blue dots. All the four points have the same distance from the red spot.
Any idea how to get their coordinates by getting use of the red spot coordinate.
Thank you in Advance

Comment: To make sure I understood correctly... For each position of your rope, you want to detect the crossing point and then four points that are on the rope, at a given distance from the crossing point? If yes, then I think that your problem is very difficult to solve without additional constraints/assumptions on the pose of the rope relative to the camera and the color/texture of the background. If as in your example, the rope is in a plane perpendicular to the camera with a white background, you could detect edges and turn them into connected components, and compute the distance like that...

Comment: Draw a circle with the red dot as center. Find the pixels where the rope and the circle intersect. You should get exactly four connected components. Those are your blue dots.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think there might be a problem with that approach if there could be kinks or bends in the rope which would affect the distance of the blue point from the red point, wouldn't there? I mean you are really assuming that the ropes are straight radii from the red point.

Comment: @MarkSetchell agreed, this was the whole point of my comment: not only bends but viewpoint changes also will affect the distance in the projective plane.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: well, the OP just says "All the four points have the same distance from the red spot." It doesn't specify what type of distance. Obviously it's somewhat more involved computing the distance along the rope, but if the distance is small w.r.t. the possible curvature of the rope, both distances would be fairly similar.

Answer (score 2):

Although you're using ORB, you're still going to need an algorithm to segment the rope from the background, or at least some technique to identify image chunks that belong to the rope and that are equidistant from the red dot. There are a number of options to explore.

It's important to consider your lighting & imaging as separate problems to be solved if this is meant to be a real-world application. This looks a bit like a problem for a class rather than for a application you'll sell and support, but you should still consider lighting:

- Will your algorithm(s) still work when light level is reduced?
- How will detection be affected by changes in camera pose relative to the surface where the rope will be located?
- If you'll be detecting "black" rope, will the algorithm also be required to detect rope of different colors? dirty rope? rope on different backgrounds?

Since you're object of interest is rope, you have to consider a class of algorithms suitable for detection of non-rigid objects. Always consider the simplest solution first!

**Connected Components**
Connected components labeling is a traditional image processing algorithm and still suitable as the starting point for many applications. The last I knew, this was implemented in OpenCV as findContours(). This can also be called "blob finding" or some variant thereof.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours

Depending on lighting, you may have to take different steps to binarize the image before running connected components. As a start, convert the color image to grayscale, which will simplify the task significantly.

1. Try a manual threshold since you can quickly test a number of values to see the effect. Don't be too discouraged if the binarization isn't quite right--this can often be fixed with preprocessing.
2. If a range of manual thresholds works (e.g. 52 - 76 in an 8-bit grayscale range), then use an algorithm that will automatically calculate the threshold for you: Otsu, entropy-based methods, etc., will all offer comparable performance. Whichever technique works best, the code/algorithm can be tweaked further to optimize for your rope application.
3. If thresholding and binarization don't work--which for your rope application seems unlikely, at least how you've presented it--then switch to thinking in terms of gradient-based (edge-based, energy-based) techniques.

But assuming you can separate the rope from the background, you're still going to need a method to start at the red dot [within the rope] and move equal distances out to the blue points. More about that later after a discussion of other rope segmentation methods.

Note: connected components labeling can work in scenarios beyond just binarizing black & white images. If you can create a texture field or some other 2D representation of the image that makes it possible to distinguish the black rope from the relatively light background, you may be able to use a connected components algorithm. (Finding a "more complicated" or "more modern" algorithm isn't necessarily going to be the right approach.)

In a binarized image, blobs can be nested: on a white background you can have several black blobs, inside of one or more of which are white blobs, inside of which are black blobs, etc. An earlier version of OpenCV handled this reasonably well. (OpenCV is a nice starting point, and a touchpoint for many, but for a number of reasons it doesn't always compare favorably to other open source and commercial packages; popularity notwithstanding, OpenCV has some issues.)

Once you have a "blob" (a 4-connected region of pixels) in a 2D digital image, you can treat the blob as an object, at which point you have a number of options:

- Edge tracing: trace around the inside and outside edges of the blob. From what I recall, OpenCV does (or at least should) have some relatively straightforward method to get the edges.
- Split the blob into component blobs, each of which can be treated separately
- Convert the blob to a polygon
- ...

A connected components algorithm should be high on the list of techniques to try if you have a non-rigid object.

**Boolean Operations**
Once you have the rope as a connected component (and possibly even without this), you can use boolean image operations to find the spots at the blue dots in your image:

1. Create a circular region in data, or even in the image
2. Find the intersection of the circle (an annulus) and the black region representing the rope. Using your original image, you should have four regions.
3. Find the center point of the intersection regions.

You could even try this without using connected components at all, but using connected components as part of the solution could make it more robust.

**Polygon Simplification**
If you have a blob, which in your application would be a connected set of black pixels representing the rope on the floor, then you can consider converting this blob to one or more polygons for further processing. There are advantages to working with polygons.

If you consider only the outside boundary of the rope, then you can see that the set of pixels defining the boundary represents a polygon. It's a polygon with a lot of points, and not a convex polygon, but a polygon nonetheless.

To simplify the polygon, you can use an algorithm such as Ramer-Douglas-Puecker:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Once you have a simplified polygon, you can try a few techniques to render useful data from the polygon

- Angle Bisector Network
- Triangulation (e.g. using ear clipping)

Triangulation is typically dependent on initial conditions, so the resulting triangulation for slighting different polygons (that is, rope -> blob -> polygon -> simplified polygon). So in your application it might be useful to triangulate the dark rope region, and then to connect the center of one triangle to the center of the next nearest triangle. You'll also have to deal with crossings, such as the rope overlap. Ultimately this can yield a "skeletonization" of the rope. Speaking of which...

**Skeletonization**
If the rope problem was posed to you as a class exercise, then it may have been a prompt to try skeletonization. You can read about it here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton

Skeletonization and thinning have their own problems to solve, but you should dig into them a bit and see those problems themselves.

The Medial Axis Transform (MAT) is a related concept. Long story there.

**Edge-based techniques**
There are a number of techniques to generate "edge images" based on edge strength, energy, entropy, etc. Making them robust takes a little effort. If you've had academic training in image processing you've likely heard of Harris, Sobel, Canny, and similar processing methods--none are magic bullets, but they're simple and dependable and will yield data you need.

An "edge image" consists of pixels representing the image gradient strength [and sometimes the gradient direction]. People may call this edge image something else, but it's the concept that matters.

What you then do with the edge data is another subject altogether. But one reason to think of edge images (or at least object borders) is that it reduces the amount of information your algorithm(s) will need to process.

**Mean Shift (and related)**
To get back to segmentation mentioned in the section on connected components, there are other methods for segmenting figures from a background: K-means, mean shift, and so on. You probably won't need any of those, but they're neat and worth studying.

**Stroke Width Transform**
This is an intriguing technique used to extract text from noisy backgrounds. Although it's intended for OCR, it could work for rope since the rope width is relatively constant, the rope shape varies, there are crossings, etc.

In short, and simplifying quite a bit, you can think of SWT as a means to find "strokes" (thick lines) by finding gradients antiparallel to each other. On either side of a stroke (or line), the edge gradient points normal to the object edge. The normal on one side of the stroke points opposite the direction of the normal on the other side of the stroke. By filtering for pixel-gradient pairs within a certain distance of each other, you can isolate certain strokes--even automatically. For your example the collection of points representing edge pairs for the rope would be much more common than other point pairs.

**Non-Rigid Matching**
There are techniques for matching non-rigid shapes, but they would not be worth exploring. If any of the techniques I mentioned above is unfamiliar to you, explore some of those first before you try any fancier algorithms.

**CNNs, machine learning, etc.**
Just don't even think of these methods as a starting point.

**Other Considerations**
If this were an application for industry, security, or whatnot, you'd have to determine how well your image processing worked under all environmental considerations. That's not an easy task, and can make all the difference between a setup that "works" in the lab and a setup that actually works in practice.

I hope that's of some help. Feel free to post a reply if I've confused more than helped, or if you want to explore some idea in more detail. Though I tried to touch on some common(ish) techniques, I didn't mention all the different ways of addressing this problem.

And briefly: once you have a skeleton, point network, or whatever representing a reduced data set for the rope and the red dot (the identified feature), a few techniques to find the items at the blue dots:

- For a skeleton, trace along each "branch" of the rope outward from the know until the geodesic distance or straight-line 2D distance is the distance D that you want.
- To use geometry, create a circle of width 1 - 2 pixels. Find the intersection of that circle and the rope. Find the center point of the intersections of circle and rope. (Also described above.)

Good luck!

Comment: This is impressively detailed, it looks like you set out to write a book... :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo: soon to be available as a Kindle remaindered textbook: available for free until they mingle the hard drive.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: also sent you a LinkedIn request. Howdy!  (Above: "mingle" --> "munge")